# Why Past simple to this answer: For Three hours

Tags: grammar

Can anyone explain to me why I should use the past simple  when I've got an answer: For three hours.

Why is it "How long *did you watch* TV last night?" and not "How long *were you watching* TV last night?"

Comment: The question seems to have a flawed premise - I would imagine either *did you watch* or *were you watching* to be answerable with "for three hours."

Comment: What if the answer would be - About three hours. I turned the TV off just after my programme finished.

Comment: Both of these are perfectly grammatical, and ask for the same information. So it's not a matter of one being "correct" and the other not. What's going on is a simple economic principle -- say as little as you need to. If you add the extra wrinkle of the progressive, with an extra syllable, different verb forms, and different auxiliaries, you should have some reason for going to the trouble. It's like wearing a tuxedo to work -- you'd make your coworkers very curious. And that's what happens here; there seems to be some undetermined presupposition in the second one. Maybe it's mother speaking.

Answer (score 0):

In a comment John Lawler wrote:

> Both of these are perfectly grammatical, and ask for the same information. So it's not a matter of one being "correct" and the other not. What's going on is a simple economic principle -- say as little as you need to. If you add the extra wrinkle of the progressive, with an extra syllable, different verb forms, and different auxiliaries, you should have some reason for going to the trouble. It's like wearing a tuxedo to work -- you'd make your coworkers very curious. And that's what happens here; there seems to be some undetermined presupposition in the second one. Maybe it's mother speaking.